# How can I construct a waterfall model diagram by LaTeX in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I need to construct a Waterfall model diagram [like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082322/difference-between-classical-waterfall-and-iterative-waterfall-model):

[image: waterfall1]

[image: waterfall2]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as \documentclass{}...\begin{document} etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a minimal working example (MWE) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: You can look/google for "flowchart tikz" for example. I think that you then can adopt the solutions according to your needs.

Comment: I am still new LaTeX learner and I have very short time because of the exams. Otherwise, I will do more self effort and will not write or ask anyone !

Comment: So use `\includegraphics{}`. What on earth are you trying to do beginning to use LaTeX in the middle of exams? That's bonkers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to *Gernot* nice answer, in which is employed `chains` TikZ library and connection between nodes are establish in a loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
    node distance = 3mm and 3mm,
      start chain = A going below right,
every node/.style = {draw, text width=24mm, minimum height=12mm, align=center,
                     inner sep=1mm, fill=white, drop shadow={fill=black},  on chain=A},
                        ]
\node {Requirements}; % A-1
\node {Design};
\node {Coding and unit test};
\node {System integration};
\node {Operation and maintenance};
%
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {2,...,5}
{
  \draw[->, thick] (A-\i) -| (A-\j);
  \draw[->, thick] (A-\j) -| (A-\i);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
  {phase/.style={draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1.3cm,align=center}
  ,previous/.style={below right=0.5cm of #1}
  }
\newcommand\connect[2]%
  {\draw[->,thick] (#1) -| (#2);
   \draw[->,thick] (#2) -| (#1);
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
  \node[phase]                       (requirements) {Requirements};
  \node[phase,previous=requirements] (design)       {Design};
  \node[phase,previous=design]       (coding)       {Coding and\\unit test};
  \node[phase,previous=coding]       (integration)  {System\\integration};
  \node[phase,previous=integration]  (operation)    {Operation and\\maintenance};
  \connect{requirements}{design};
  \connect{design}{coding};
  \connect{coding}{integration};
  \connect{integration}{operation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
  {phase/.style={draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1.3cm,align=center}
  ,previous/.style={below right=0.5cm of #1}
  }
\newcommand\connect[2]%
  {\draw[->,thick] (#1.east) to[out=0,in=90] (#2.north);
   \draw[->,thick] (#2.west) to[out=180,in=270] (#1.south);
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
  \node[phase]                       (requirements) {Requirements};
  \node[phase,previous=requirements] (design)       {Design};
  \node[phase,previous=design]       (coding)       {Coding and\\unit test};
  \node[phase,previous=coding]       (integration)  {System\\integration};
  \node[phase,previous=integration]  (operation)    {Operation and\\maintenance};
  \connect{requirements}{design};
  \connect{design}{coding};
  \connect{coding}{integration};
  \connect{integration}{operation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like the connect command, very handy.